# Customizing TimeoutStopSec in a systemd unit file

Tags: systemd

Is there any way to customize the value in TimeoutStopSec in a systemd unit?  I need it to be 24 hours in some cases, but that's completely inappropriate in others.

I'd like to customize it via an EnvironmentFile.   Alternatively, I could set it via %i, but I'm already using that for something else, so I'd need a way to split %i into the part that goes to ExecStart and the part that goes to TimeoutStopSec.